# How to test client app without creating a server?

Tags: testing, browser, server-response

Is there anyway to create a server response manually to check whether my client side is working correctly to server responses? I want to do this without writing the server part myself.
What I specifically want is to test a server-sent event handling part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple extensions for Firefox and Chrome allowing you to edit the response.

**Firefox:**

- [Modify HTTP Response](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/modify-http-response/?src=stackoverflow) (only allows to modify the response body)
- [Modify Response Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/modify-response-headers/?src=stackoverflow)

**Chrome:**

- [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en-US)
- [Tamper Chrome (extension)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb?hl=en-US) (new version: [Tamper Dev](https://tamper.dev))
- [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en-US)